# django-facebook does not login facebook test user

Tags: django-authentication, django-facebook

I am creating a web app that allows users to register using their Facebook account.  I am using django-facebook to do the authentication / registration of new users.  I am trying what I think is the simplest setup, using django registration instead of userena.  Everything works well when I use my own Facebook account: I am asked to confirm that I allow the app to have access to my profile, a new account is created in the auth_user table and I am logged in.

However, when I am logged in into Facebook as a test user, I confirm that I allow the app and then I am redirected to facebook/connect/?facebook_login=1&attempt=1&code=AQBM0-z......
The new account is not created.

Here are my relevant settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = NNN
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = NNNN
FACEBOOK_REGISTRATION_BACKEND ='django_facebook.registration_backends.FacebookRegistrationBackend'

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'django_facebook.FacebookProfile'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the whole problem is that django-facebook removes the long emails from the facebook data.  This makes the auth not be able to create an account.

I just commented out the following lines in api.py

```
if len(user_data.get('email', '')) > 75:
    #no more fake email accounts for facebook
    del user_data['email']
```